# get specific elements from array,List in perl, in single line

Tags: perl

We can use range operator to get sequence of elements.

But is there any way to get say **3rd 7th and 11th** element from an array in a single statement.

Comment: No, use `grep` or C like `for` loop if you want every 4-th element.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure

```
my @selection = @array[2,6,10]
```

Comment: Take a look at the Slices documentation for more information [`perldoc perldata#slices`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)